# Convert Zigfu joint position from Real World to Projective like in OpenNI

Tags: javascript, kinect, openni

OpenNI provides the function [`ConvertRealWorldToProjective`](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/classxn_1_1_depth_generator_a70cda9f296d0ac90088cfafc34e9edd2.html) which lets you easily convert real world (x,y,z) joint positions, in mm, to a projected (x,y) position in pixels for a given viewport. This is really useful for drawing a 'skeleton' over the webcam feed.

Is this functionality exposed by ZigJS, either as a function or perhaps already converted somewhere? I can't find any mention of it in [the docs](http://zigfu.com/static/apidoc/files/zig-js.html), but [I had luck with a previously undocumented feature with Zigfu in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543248/access-kinect-rgb-image-data-from-zigjs).

```
user.addEventListener('userupdate', function(user) {
  var real = user.skeleton[zig.Joint.Head].position; // this is real world coordinate
  // anything exposed by zigfu to convert to real world?
});
```

If not provided by Zigfu, does anyone know of a good JavaScript library that provides this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZigJS exposes two (unfortunately still undocumented) methods: `convertImageToWorldSpace` and `convertWorldToImageSpace`. They both accept an array of coordinates where every 3 elements represent a single point, and they return the converted points.

**EDIT**

To save anyone else the trial and error, it is the embedded object, not `zig` itself that has the undocumented methods. Example:

```
var zigObj = zig.findZigObject();

user.addEventListener('userupdate', function(user) {
  var real = user.skeleton[zig.Joint.Head].position;
  var projective = zigObj.convertWorldToImageSpace(real);
  // do something with the converted position, like drawing it over the webcam
});
```